# "How do I do" or "what do I do"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I asked a programming question on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56659213/10253483).

I did some work, and need a step forward, which one is more clear and idiomatic?

> **1**: How do I do next?
>
> **2**: What do I do next?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expression 2 is more clear and idiomatic. and "What should I do next?" would be better.

Comment: This answer could be vastly improved if you explained how Expression 1 doesn't sound grammatical, and how the OP could phase the question if we wanted to start with _how_.